# Installing a new Location Provider

Tags: android, location-provider

There is an entry in 1.5 of the SDK for installLocationProvider. That entry is marked: @hide.
I would like to provide an alternate location provider, the why is not important, just the how.
Does anyone know the "trick" for using the "installLocationProvider" entry point or where to find details of building a complete or partial solution? The "Mock" location provider code is not usable in a finished application.

Comment: I'd be really interested too know how to do this too..

Comment: You're going to get a lot more help if you retag this with the technology about which you're asking. I'm guessing it is Android, how is anyone supposed to know that if it isn't mentioned anywhere?

Comment: Just added that - you're right. we're talking about android here.

Comment: Have you tried using reflection API ?

Answer (score 1):

From everything that I have read, access to this is only allowed for Google and their special partners. This is not to say there isn't some sort of hack that can be performed from the native sdk, but I have no clue about that.

If you're just out to get a better service, you should look at something like the Skyhook SDK http://www.skyhookwireless.com/developers/
Its not free but they base their cost on your application.